# problems restoring image file with dd

Tags: linux, dd

I have a pendrive where I restore an image maked by dd command in other system.
When I restore the image, always I must do a fsck.
Is possbile that when I've generated the image the source system was corrupted or it is that I corrupt the pendrive when I restore the image file ?
Many thanks and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just guessing, since you do not provide much information about the creation of the image, but yes, it is possible that the file system was in an unclean state when the image was taken. It is also possible that the file system was simply *still mounted* at that point of time - always unmount a file system (or mount it read-only) before you take an image of it.

Comment: Is an image of my raspberry pi. The FS was mounted. So, there is some way to check errors before I put the image in my pendrive? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could bind the image to a loopback device (using `losetup`, IIRC), then `fsck` the loopback device, unbind the image from the loopback device and only then write the image to the USB device.

Comment: Did you mean: losetup /dev/loop0 /my dd_image. Then fsck /dev/loop. And then the dd command?

Answer (score 1):

To know if you have corruption in your data, when you create an image, you should compute a [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) (md5sum or sha1).

```
# dd if=/dev/sdb of=my_image.img  # --> here you create your image
# md5sum /dev/sdb                 # --> here you compute your checksum
e2985322ca0ed3632027a6eb8fe70ae8  /dev/sdb
# md5sum my_image.img             # --> check the integrity of the image
e2985322ca0ed3632027a6eb8fe70ae8  my_image.img
```

Thus, when you flash to another device, on an other computer or any system, you are able to check the integrity of data.

```
# dd if=my_image.img of=/dev/hdc  # --> here you flash your image to a device
# md5sum /dev/hdc                 # --> check the integrity of the flashed data
e2985322ca0ed3632027a6eb8fe70ae8  /dev/hdc
```

Of course the obtained hash here is just an example but it is always the same for the same data. If any byte was altered the checksum would be totally different.

Obviously, if you copy with `dd` to a device (even from), be sure that one is not mounted using something like `mount | grep /dev/hdc` should return nothing if you want to flash the `dev/hdc` device.

Comment: Thanks.Very useful info. The problem is that I cant generate the image now, so I can't make md5sum